# How to find the orientation of a plane?

Tags: geometry, rotation, orientation, sympy, pose

I have three non-colinear 3D points, let's say `pt1`, `pt2`, `pt3`. I've computed the plane `P` using the [`sympy.Plane`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/plane.html). How can I find the orientation of this plane(`P`) i.e. RPY(euler angles) or in quaternion?

Comment: You can get the normal to the plane as `p.normal_vector`. The orientation as a quaternion or Euler angles is not uniquely defined though (the plane can be rotated into itself).

Answer (score 0):

I never used sympy, but you should be able to find a function to get the angle between 2 vectors (your normal vector and the world Y axis.)

```
theta = yaxis.angle_between(P.normal_vector)
```

then get the rotation axis, which is the normalized cross product of those same vectors.

```
axis = yaxis.cross(P.normal_vector).normal()
```

Then construct a quaternion from the axis and angle

```
q = Quaternion.from_axis_angle(axis, theta)
```